# Can I get a list of AWS EC2 instances running for each of my accounts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a list of AWS accounts with account ids. I want to fetch the list of all the EC2 instances running in each of those accounts. Can I fetch that list using boto3?

Comment: You will need credentials for each AWS Account to be able to make the API requests. Or do you have IAM Roles in each account that can be assumed by one 'central' IAM User? You will also need to loop through each region in each account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can access your AWS account programmatically by creating boto3 client.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)
```

See: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#method-parameters

After creating boto3 client with your credentials, You can use boto3's [EC2.Client.describe_instances()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances)

```
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'Values': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
    ],
    InstanceIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    DryRun=True|False,
    MaxResults=123,
    NextToken='string'
)
```

Use `'instance-state-name' : 'running'` in `Filters`, like:

```
{
    'Name': 'instance-state-name',
    'Values': [
        'running',
    ]
}
```

then you can get informations of your running ec2 instances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where should I specify the account id for which I want the list of instances?

Comment: Updated to include that :)

Answer (score 0):

To access AWS Account from CLI/Programs, you need to have 'aws_access_key_id_value' and 'aws_secret_access_key_value'. Once you have these details, you can use the following code to list EC2 instances from the AWS Account you specified keys of.

Create config.properties with the following code.

```
aws_access_key_id_value='YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-OF-THE-AWS-ACCOUNT'
aws_secret_access_key_value='YOUR-SECRETE-KEY-OF-THE-AWS-ACCOUNT'
```

Create list-ec2-instances.py with the following code.

```
import boto3

def getVarFromFile(filename):
    import imp
    f = open(filename)
    global data
    data = imp.load_source('data', '', f)
    f.close()

getVarFromFile('config.properties')

ec2client = boto3.resource(

    'ec2',
    aws_access_key_id=data.aws_access_key_id_value,
    aws_secret_access_key=data.aws_secret_access_key_value
)

for instance in ec2client.instances.all():
     print(
         "Id: {0}\nPlatform: {1}\nType: {2}\nPublic IPv4: {3}\nAMI: {4}\nState: {5}\n".format(
         instance.id, instance.platform, instance.instance_type, instance.public_ip_address, instance.image.id, instance.state
         )
     )
```

Execute the following command.

```
python list-ec2-instances.py
```